# Multiple Passwords in Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, password

Is there a possibility to store a second password in the Windows Active Directory? I mean an attribute which has the same behavoir as the unicodeWPD field.

Answer (score 3):

There's is no option of having a second password store at native Microsoft AD. Do you need to know about any attribute available in AD to store the password as secondary storage or you want to save one or more password for a user in AD.

Answer (score 1):

You can always [extend the schema](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759633%28WS.10%29.aspx) of your Active Directory forest, to meet any need you might have.

I think you're asking the wrong question though. If your aim is to be able to authenticate using any one of a number of passwords, the authentication methods you use need to "know" about your second password

Comment: Don't even have to extend the schema, really.  He could always use one of the existing, unused attributes (like one of the default "Custom Attributes").  Probably not a great approach, but it's doable.